# Scope based on many possible exclusions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

How do I create a scope that basically says this:

```
scope :filtered, where('status != one string, another string, yet another, yep, even more')
```

So basically saying "status does not equal any of the following strings."

And that list of strings will expand over time.

Note, I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (Not tested)

```
scope :filtered, where(["status <> ALL ( ARRAY[?, ?] )", 'string_1', 'string_2'])
```

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL, sorry about not clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
scope :filtered, where(["status NOT IN (?)", ["string1", "string2", "string3"]])
```